# Wildfly Deployment Issue- dependency resolution

Tags: deployment, wildfly

I have a jar and a war file.
jar file is say x.jar and war file is y.war.
I have a jboss-deployment-structure.xml which specifies that y.war is dependent on x.jar.
Now I want these two files to be deployed in the following sequence x.jar followed by y.war.
I have a class in y module which is annotated with @Startup, which uses a class of x module and fails.
Please let me know how to solve this issue.

Comment: Could you please copy & paste some code? What you have tried so far? So we can start with what is already working for you :)

Comment: Why don't you put `x.jar` in the `WEB-INF/lib` directory of `y.war`?

Comment: x.jar is actually created by building a module x, I do not want to copy the jar into WEB-INF/lib every time I make any code changes in module x. I just want wildfly to deploy them in sequence that is x.jar first and then y.war. Is there any way to do that?